# Dealing with numeric (decimal) dates in R?

Tags: r, date, datetime, lubridate

I have some numeric date data from Excel:

```
> df <- data.frame(c(42613, 42612, 42614), c(42614.61, 42613.97, 42612.12))
> names(df) <- c("Closetime", "Opentime")
```

Both `Closetime` and `Opentime` are `numeric`. I want to preserve the hour/minute/second data from `OpenTime` and add the time '00:00:00' to every date in `Closetime`:

```
> df$Closetime <- paste(as.Date(df$Closetime, origin = '1900-01-01'), c('00:00:00'))
```

Easy enough to do `Closetime`, but when I try using `lubridate::date_decimal` on `Opentime`, everything goes to hell.

```
> df$Opentime <- date_decimal(df$Opentime)
> df
            Closetime             Opentime
1 2016-09-02 00:00:00 42614-08-11 15:36:00
2 2016-09-01 00:00:00 42613-12-21 01:12:00
3 2016-09-03 00:00:00 42612-02-13 22:04:48
```

How can I get both `Opentime` and `Closetime` to be of the same type/format? I am eventually looking to be able to get the difference, in hours, between the times in each column, for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use POSIXct, you can do for example

```
df$Opentime <- as.POSIXct( df$Opentime*24*60*60, 
                origin="1900-01-01", 
                tz="UTC")
```

Reasoning: POSIXct is just number of seconds since origin

Comment: Well, that is the worst possible approach of scaling days to seconds as your *loose* eg the couple of adjustment seconds.  The other answers show how to do this properly using R's types.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel fair point, but perhaps if you do all the intermediate conversions, you should point out what purpose that serves.

Comment: Come again?  Are referring to my answer below?   Can you read?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel yeah I am referring to your answer below

Comment: Three steps, three blocks, each commented. If you have questions, I suggest you ask them.  I told you here that your approach has flaws; that got two upvotes. I'll let you figure out the rest.

Answer (score 2):

First we follow the advice in `help("as.Date")` regarding Excel dates. I assume here Windows Excel:

```
df$Closetime_p <- as.Date(df$Closetime, origin = "1899-12-30")
df$Opentime_p <- as.Date(floor(df$Opentime), origin = "1899-12-30")
```

Then we convert to POSIXct:

```
df$Closetime_p <- as.POSIXct(as.POSIXlt(df$Closetime_p, tz = "GMT"), tz = "GMT")
df$Opentime_p <- as.POSIXct(as.POSIXlt(df$Opentime_p, tz = "GMT"), tz = "GMT")
```

Now we add the time:

```
df$Opentime_p <- df$Opentime_p + (df$Opentime - floor(df$Opentime)) * 24 * 3600
#  Closetime Opentime Closetime_p          Opentime_p
#1     42613 42614.61  2016-08-31 2016-09-01 14:38:24
#2     42612 42613.97  2016-08-30 2016-08-31 23:16:48
#3     42614 42612.12  2016-09-01 2016-08-30 02:52:48
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert to date as you do, then convert to `POSIXct`:

First, create the data.frame (and note how we set the column names):

```
R> df <- data.frame(CloseT=c(42613, 42612, 42614), OpenT=c(42614.61, 42613.97, 42612.12))
R> df
  CloseT   OpenT
1  42613 42614.6
2  42612 42614.0
3  42614 42612.1
R>
```

Then convert to Date:

```
R> df$CloseT <- as.Date(df$CloseT, origin="1900-01-01")
R> df$OpenT <- as.Date(df$OpenT, origin="1900-01-01")
R> df
      CloseT      OpenT
1 2016-09-02 2016-09-03
2 2016-09-01 2016-09-02
3 2016-09-03 2016-09-01
R>
```

Finally, convert to `POSIXct`:

```
R> df$OpenT <- as.POSIXct(df$OpenT)
R> df$CloseT <- as.POSIXct(df$CloseT)
R> df
               CloseT               OpenT
1 2016-09-01 19:00:00 2016-09-03 09:38:24
2 2016-08-31 19:00:00 2016-09-02 18:16:48
3 2016-09-02 19:00:00 2016-08-31 21:52:48
R>
```

Going via `POSIXlt` allows you to set a timezone, as Roland showed.

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation on date_decimal:

> a POSIXct object, whose year corresponds to the integer part of decimal.

```
date <- ymd("2009-02-10")
decimal <- decimal_date(date)  # 2009.11
date_decimal(decimal) # "2009-02-10 UTC"
```

So in your example, it's interpreting 42614 as the year.

Try using `as.POSIXct`. You may have to specify the time zone, but if all you need is the delta this won't be necessary. Below I've calculated the time difference:

```
df <- data.frame(c(42613, 42612, 42614), c(42614.61, 42613.97, 42612.12))
names(df) <- c("Closetime", "Opentime")
df$Closetime <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(df$Closetime, origin = '1900-01-01'))
df$Opentime <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(df$Opentime, origin = '1900-01-01'))
df$delta <- df$Opentime - df$Closetime
df
            Closetime            Opentime      delta
1 2016-09-01 20:00:00 2016-09-03 10:38:24  1.61 days
2 2016-08-31 20:00:00 2016-09-02 19:16:48  1.97 days
3 2016-09-02 20:00:00 2016-08-31 22:52:48 -1.88 days
```

Based on the comment, if you want to make sure the display has the correct hour, you'll need to match timezones correctly. You can do this after the conversion to `as.POSIXct` by setting the `tzone` attribute.

```
df <- data.frame(c(42613, 42612, 42614), c(42614.61, 42613.97, 42612.12))
names(df) <- c("Closetime", "Opentime")
df$Closetime <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(df$Closetime, origin = '1900-01-01'))
df$Opentime <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(df$Opentime, origin = '1900-01-01'))
attr(df$Closetime, "tzone") <- "GMT"
attr(df$Opentime, "tzone") <- "GMT"
df$delta <- df$Opentime - df$Closetime
df

   Closetime            Opentime      delta
1 2016-09-02 2016-09-03 14:38:24  1.61 days
2 2016-09-01 2016-09-02 23:16:48  1.97 days
3 2016-09-03 2016-09-01 02:52:48 -1.88 days
```

Comment: If I wanted `Closetime` to have the time `00:00:00` for all values, how would I do that? Is there a parameter I need to specify?

Comment: Never mind, I was able to accomplish that using `lubridate::hour` and setting `hour(df$Closetime) <- 0`.

Comment: if your goal is to calculate the difference between the two, this might throw off your calculation. I'll edit to show how you can force it to GMT timezone so that `Closetime` remains without an hour.

Comment: @not_a_robot:  _If_ you are in same timezone as the object and if h/m/d are all zero the format drops those and you see just the date.  That is a feature, not a bug.